# ansible: trigger same handler from multiple roles at the end of the playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

My ansible playbook includes several roles, for example `dovecot`, `postfix`, `postgres` and `rspamd`. All of them require SSL certificates, which are generated by the `certbot` (lets encrypt) role. For this reason and for easier handling all roles follow the same data structure to define SSL certificates with different requirements:

```yaml
certbot_domains: []

dovecot_domains: 
- name: imap1.example.com
  subject_alternative_names: []
- name: imap1.department-a.example.com
  subject_alternative_names: []
- name: pop3.example.com
  subject_alternative_names: []
- name: pop3.department-a.example.com
  subject_alternative_names: []

postfix_domains:
- name: smtp1.example.com
  subject_alternative_names:
  - smtp1.department-a.example.com

postgres_domains: 
- name: postgres.example.com
  subject_alternative_names: []

rspamd_domains:
- name: rspamd.example.com
  subject_alternative_names: 
  - rspamd.department-a.example.com
```

However, I want to avoid including the role `certbot` in the roles `dovecot`, `postfix`, `postgres` and `rspamd` which automtically creates the certificate, because each time will be installed `nginx`, vhosts.conf files for each domain and some snippets to provide the path `/.well-known/acme-challange` as alias.

To avoid each time to install `nginx`, configure the snippets and so on should be the tasks only run once. The variable `certbot_domains` shall be extended by `dovecot_domains`, `postfix_domains`, `postgres_domains` and `rspamd_domains` and the installation of nginx and their vhosts should be the last task. Perhaps the following graphic can describe the problem more precisely.

[image]

If there is already something from ansible, I would be very grateful for a small snippet that makes the solution more understandable.

Comment: After reading your question several times in the last days, I'm very unclear if you want to run a specific handler after all tasks, or just make sure you don't run the same role twice, or <add whatever here because I'm lost>. My 2cent: craft an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to illustrate your exact problem.

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator, I have described the problem in more detail. I hope it is now more understandable

Comment: where exactly do you define the certbot domains (in inventory, in your playbook ... ?) and how exactly and for which tasks the "non-certbot" roles use that info ?

Comment: The `certbot_domains` var is defined in the `roles/certbot/default/main.yaml`. For "non-certbot" roles, if they are like setting up unix users or update system roles for example, is the `certbot_domain` var not required.

Comment: Well then I really don't get what the problem is. Those roles are totally independent. Just run them in the order you like.